# kendoui grid in mvc3 security vulnerability, how do i get around it?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, security, kendo-ui

The kendoUI grid uses HttpGet requests to update the data during an AJAX request.  (http://www.kendoui.com/documentation/asp-net-mvc/helpers/grid/ajax-binding.aspx)  The server returns a Json result, and, in order to get it to work, we need to use the following code:

```
return Json(Result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

That does the job just fine, but it's a security vulnerability (that's why Microsoft makes us put the "AllowGet" in there).

The safe way to return the Json would be in an HttpPost, but the kendoui grid doesn't allow it.

I want to use the kendoui grid.  Is there a way to use the HttpGet, return Json, and do it securely?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the MVC wrapper of the Kendo Grid this would not happen. There the grid is configured to make POST requests because of this ASP.NET MVC behavior. Make sure you have included `kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js` though. More info can be found in the [docs](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/introduction).

Comment: I have included kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js.  When I decorate my action with [HttpPost], the grid no longer updates.  It only updates if the Action is an [HttpGet].  Could you show me where in the documentation they talk about this?  In the link I provided in my question, they say that it will perform an HttpGet request.  An HttpPost is never mentioned.

Comment: Found it.  You were exactly right.  I had a miss-spelling in my script source.  Thanks!

Comment: Still, notice that Kendo Dropdownlist has this vulnerability if you load JSON data through AJAX. You have to do the following to force the Dropdownlist to use POST: .DataSource(s => s.Read(a => a.Action(DatasourceAction, DatasourceController).Type(HttpVerbs.Post))

Answer (score 2):

The kendo datasource uses GET by default when using ajax, but it is possible to use POST by defining the transport settings to post.

Here is a shortened version of the code at a [Telerik kendo CRUD example](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-examples-asp-net/blob/master/grid-wcf-crud/Default.aspx) using post.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"],
            dataSource: {
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "ProductID",
                        fields: {
                            ProductID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                            ProductName: { validation: { required: true } },
                            UnitPrice: { type: "number", validation: { required: true } }
                        }
                    }
                },
                transport: {
                    create: {
                        url: "Products.svc/Create", 
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
                        type: "POST" 
                    },
                    read: {
                        url: "Products.svc/Read",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        type: "POST"
                    },
                    parameterMap: function(data, operation) {
                        if (operation != "read") {
                            return JSON.stringify({ products: data.models })
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I see where you are able to use type: "POST", but I don't see the equivalent in MVC.  I tried 'Datasource().Read().Type("Post")', but there is no ".Type()"  There is also no "Datasource().Transport()"